# xmlHttpRequest returns status 0

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, jsfiddle

I can't get `xmlHttpRequest` to return any status but `0`. The `responseText` is always empty. No matter, which url I am opening, this happens. Could someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
var url = "http://stackoverflow.com/";
var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var response = document.getElementById("response");
xmlHttp.open("GET", url, true); // true for asynchronous
xmlHttp.send(null);
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  response.innerHTML = xmlHttp.status;
};
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6ub7ct6j/

Thanks in advance

Comment: Same origin policy and CORs

Comment: Does the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) say something like “Blocked loading mixed active content” or “Cross-Origin Request Blocked”?

Answer (score 0):

Check the console. You're trying to load an http resource from an https page, and the browser is blocking it. However, if you try https://stackoverflow.com, you'll get a CORS error.

stackoverflow.com doesn't allow access via Ajax:

`VM94:1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://stackoverflow.com/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://fiddle.jshell.net' is therefore not allowed access.`